# I am getting the bottom line for only first two characters in the dropdown in bootstrap

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

In my code, I am getting the bottom borders for only "High Spot" but I need to get the border for all the label help me with this

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="text" class="font-weight-bold"> What is the preferred order methodology? </label>
      <br>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn dropdown-toggle border-bottom" data-toggle="dropdown">
          High Spot Frequency.Low Avg.Rate
      </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in a stackblitz

Comment: ok i wll try that and post in soon

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys i get the answer just by adding the css and increase the width